# MS SQL Entries that expire after 24 hours

Tags: php, sql-server

Based on the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410762/sql-entries-that-expire-after-24-hours) I tried using:

```
CREATE EVENT delete_expired_101
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 24 HOUR DO
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id = 101;
```

on my php query, but it doesn't seem to work and gives me invalid syntax. Can you  recommend me a way for this?

Take note I am using MS SQL not MySQL.

Comment: That is not compatible with T-SQL.  You will have to build a process to delete data based on a timestamp which is stored as a column on the table.  This could simply be a stored procedure that purges data over 24 hours old and called by a SQL Agent job.

Comment: so by that you mean i have to use sql agent job instead? X_X

Comment: if so, would you at least give me the right detailed procedures on doing this for me? i would really appreciate that.

Comment: Simple as: DELETE FROM my_table WHERE DateValue >= DATEADD(hh,-24, GETDATE())

The table should we be created like:
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
DateValue DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE(),
Column1,
Column2,
.
.
)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use SQL Agent.  The logic could be a SQL Agent job that is fired every 24 hours that deletes any data that has a datetime less than `DATEADD(d,-1,getdate())`.  Please do some research on how to implement SQL Agent.  If you need help with the code to delete data in a table based on a datetime value, please open a new question that includes that table's schema.

Comment: There are other ways to run code against a SQL Server database, but not by creating an "event"

Comment: I might choose to use DELETE script instead by adding a column as the initial timestamps will be stored. Thanks for all the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Ill be choosing @Chris H's suggestion by using delete function and set a table column which records timestamps.

Thanks for all the help