# Delete a post after a period of time

Tags: php, mysql, article

I have created a function that gets the time an article was published. The same function checks whether the article is 1 week old and deactivates it.

I don't know what to do here if I have to make the function responsive when I call. I thought of using JavaScript and setting a timeout for the function. that would be too much of looping.

This is the "if" that I used to check the date. Someone with a better idea, please help.

```
if((time() - $publish_time) > (7*24*60*60)){
  //  if the current timestamp - the time the article was published > 1 week.
  //Execute the query to deactivate the article
}
```

That snippet is inside a function that I have to call.

Comment: why would you use client-side stuff to delete posts. make it time out in your database instead...

Comment: seems to be a great idea. but how?

Comment: Its called an EVENT and you can create one with [this tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/)

Comment: @RicardoOrtegaMagaña ooh, I havent seen this before.

Comment: i checked and the tutorial is helping. but am still trying to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine that [table] has [column] with the [date](http://www.ntchosting.com/mysql/insert-date.html) of the post got inserted:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;

CREATE
    EVENT 'archive_posts'
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 WEEK
    DO 
        DELETE FROM [table] WHERE [column] < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK);
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having this inside your site, you should expire your articles with a cronjob, as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9865393/how-to-delete-mysql-row-after-time-passes) when using MySQL (*nix-like)
On Windows, you can use `mmc.exe` and add a Task to execute the script through [Task Scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler))