# Auto Delete Row from Database Certain Time

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin

Is it possible to `auto delete data/row from my database` after a certain time? eg. after 3months

I'am using phpmyadmin for my database.

Comment: Yes, you can use cron job http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9865393/how-to-delete-mysql-row-after-time-passes

Answer (score 4):

You can schedule events in mysql.

Have a look on this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html

Comment: This is the best solution. phpMyAdmin supports interacting with the event scheduler by looking for the Event tab from within your database. Combine it with what Sutandiono said about having a field for knowing when a row was inserted so your code can figure out what to delete.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do the following:

1. Ensure your data contain either insertion date, or the date when you want them to be deleted.
2. Write a script to delete expired records.
3. Put the script in a cron job, running once a day.
4. ???
5. Profit.

It's not related to phpmyadmin, btw.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CRON for that.

If you have a linux server, you can install crontab, and if not, you have some website like http://www.cronjobonline.com/..

Comment: Let me clarify this one sir. i dont have a linux server but i have a windows server. wherein my xampp is located. how to create website similar to cronjobonline?

Answer (score 0):

You can  use MySQL **events** ..as

```
CREATE EVENT delete_class_data

ON SCHEDULE EVERY 7 DAY

DO

DELETE FROM <code>class</code>;
```

and delete specific data older than 7 days..are whatever you want. You can include date of entry in that table.